# Xsane does not recognize scanner Brother DCP-135C - Xsane não reconhece scanner Brother DCP-135C

Tags: 14.04, printing, scanner, brother

Já palmei vários tópicos mas ainda não resolvi este problema. A impressora funciona direitinho, mas o scanner não, Drivers e xsane estão instalados. Tentei resolver alterando o ficheiro /lib/udev/rules.d/40-libsane.rules (li essa dica no forum) mas dá-me "permissão negada". Como posso fazer a alteração se não consigo abrir o ficheiro no terminal por mais que tente (tentei como root) ?
Agradeço qualquer ajuda. Há uns dez anos que não uso linux, mas agora que instalei o ubuntu 14 fiquei fã. Só é pena realmente o scanner não funcionar.

**English translation from Portuguese**

I have read many other questions but have not yet solved this problem. The printer works all right, but the scanner does not, and drivers and `xsane` are both installed.

I tried to solve by changing the `/lib/udev/rules.d/40-libsane.rules` file (I read this tip in the forum) but keep getting `permission denied`.

How can I make the change if I can not open the file on the terminal for more than read-only (try opening it as root maybe)? I appreciate any help. It has been over 10 years since I have used Linux, but I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 and I love it!

Comment: Translation coming soon...

Answer (score 1):

You need to open that file as root by running:

```
sudo vi /lib/udev/rules.d/40-libsane.rules
```

Then you will be able to edit the file and save it.  You can replace `vi` with whatever text editor you normally use.

**In Portuguese:**

Você precisa abrir esse arquivo como raiz executando:

```
sudo vi /lib/udev/rules.d/40-libsane.rules
```

Em seguida, você será capaz de editar o arquivo e salvá-lo. Você pode substituir `vi` com qualquer editor de texto que você usa normalmente.